# How do I make the Clothier appear?

Tags: terraria

Terraria just updated to 1.04, and the changelog indicates a new NPC -- a Clothier.

What are the requirements to get this NPC to move in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He's the Old Man from the dungeon, so you have to defeat him in his Skeletron form to rid him of his curse.

You also need proper NPC housing, of course.